# SignalR Funq Dependency

Tags: c#-4.0, dependency-injection, ninject, signalr, funq

I'm trying to inject Signalr dependencies with Funq D.I.

The process is explained pretty well [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/extensibility/dependency-injection) and I tried also to follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19626244/signalr-2-0-in-vs2012-registration-and-dependency-injection) question.

and the [Ninject](https://gist.github.com/riccardod/5d3b2fe7552cccb8e31e) version works pretty well.

Now I am trying to convert it to a Funq version using this [gist](https://gist.github.com/aaronlerch/5345587) for FunqDependencyResolver.
but this [Funq version](https://gist.github.com/riccardod/a88e1b87ea2bba7340f5) is not working and gives the "System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object" that should be because it's not registering dependencies.

Is this because the Ninject version is resolving to a method?

Answer (score 3):

We used Windsor, but the process is the same for any IoC:

First create your resolver, inherit from signalR DefaultDependencyResolver:

```
public class CustomContainerResolver: DefaultDependencyResolver
{
        public CustomContainerResolver(IocContainer instance)
        {
            _instance = instance;
        }

        public override object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _instance.Instance.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType) ? _instance.GetService(serviceType) : base.GetService(serviceType);
        }

        public override IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return _instance.Instance.Kernel.HasComponent(serviceType) ? _instance.GetAllInstances(serviceType): base.GetServices(serviceType);
        }
}
```

In your Startup:

```
var signalrDependency = new CustomContainerResolver(container);
```

then, as usual

```
app.MapSignalR(hubConfiguration);
```

Comment: I linked to the Funq dependency resolver I used in the original question and it's also very similar to the Ninject one that is working perfectly
https://gist.github.com/aaronlerch/5345587
Apparently with Funq something is missing.